# Have you ever tried Apache POI with a shared excel?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, shared-memory

I am trying to have a java program type into an excel that is shared to several users. Although the java program works fine when no users are accessing the excel file at the time it is run, it seems to create a duplicate file or something entirely new when others are accessing it simultaneously. Is this an issue with my code or is Apache POI just not compatible with a shared excel file? I can include my code but I have a sinking feeling that a simple yes/no will suffice.

Comment: I've checked for a duplicate as this seems such a common question, but couldn't find something appropriate. So the answer is, Apache POI doesn't work with shared access.

Comment: If you're on a unix-based system, there's no issue with Apache POI generating a spreasheet that someone else already has open. If you're on Windows, the file system semantics are different, and you can't have any external program (Apache POI or not) recreating a file that is already open+locked in Excel